# Opening up PDFs locally on device with PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, offline-browsing

How can I open up a pdf file locally on my device through my app? I used window.open to try an open up the pdf but it won't work. Is there another way to achieve this?

By the way I'm using AppPresser's offline function to make this work. I have individual html pages working offline, I just can't open pdf files inside of those pages.

Thank you!

Comment: If the PDF is available locally in device, you can try out file opener plugin in combination with file plugin

Answer (score 1):

You can attempt such a action by basically using google pdf viewer app.